# Codeigniter no input file specified error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have installed CI in subdirecotry www.siteb.com/rexona

My .htaccess inside www.siteb.com/rexona :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rexona

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#‘system’ can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn’t true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
#Submitted by Michael Radlmaier (mradlmaier)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

In config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Whenever I try access controllers I get **No input file specified**. However it does load default controller, but I cant access any methods in default controller either.

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your `uri_protocol` needs to be set to something - at least set it to auto.

The error you are getting is because PHP runs as CGI which means you need to pass the URL rewrite to `index.php?/$1` instead (note the question mark).

Comment: will this still work if I'd move code to a server where PHP runs as apache module?

Comment: @Peter If the `uri_protocol`configuration is set to AUTO, I would suspect it does. Though, I would not recommend using server settings specific for one type of implementation when the server uses another.

Comment: thanks, it works on live hosting and also error error related to unable load dynamic library is disappeared

Comment: @Repox please tell More about this. I am curious and I can't find anywhere answer for this question, Why do we actually need here this question mark after index.php? And what does it do? How does it work? I had project where I hadn't this question mark and it worked. And now I got other project, and it doesn't work with it. What is this all about?

Comment: @KrystianPolska The question mark is a part of the URI; it enabled CodeIgniter to route based on the input in the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` the variable. Some applications have a different approach, which probably is the case in your situation.

Answer (score 4):

Godaddy hosting, it seems fixed `on.htaccess`, myself it is working by changing:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$config['uri_protocol']` should not be empty. The default is `AUTO`, passing in an empty string will break the core URI class, which is used to route your requests through the Router class.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'AUTO' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

As the comments say: *"If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors"*.
 Empty string is not one of those flavors, it would end up trying to read from `$_SERVER['']`, which is normally going to be empty.

Comment: Hi, I tried all options but with no success.... Where could be the problem? Is it .htaccess or CI configuration or server...?

Comment: Thnks, left it on auto. For some reason I thought that leaving it blank would set it to default.

Comment: From looking at CI's source code, I didn't see a reason why an empty string could not do the same job as "AUTO". I personally think it would make sense and be more consistent with other config items, it's just the way they chose to do it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error in hostinger free account, resolve with the issue presented by jhon foo above.

my .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /MY_SUBFOLDER_UNDER_HTML_DIRECTORY/
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /mY_subfolder/
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$0 [QSA,L]
```

This work fine, thanks a lot!