# .htaccess with ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 gives "No input file specified"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm running Code Igniter and my .htaccess was:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
    RedirectMatch 404 /\\.svn(/.*|$)
</IfModule>
```

Then I realized that no $_GET variable was getting through.

I followed some instructions to create the .htaccess to use together with Code Igniter, and replaced the `index.php?$1` with `index.php/$1`. This works on a linux machine, but on the Windows it doesn't. I'm sure it is a server configuration, but I don't know which one.

Assuming that I access

```
http://localhost/directory/this_is_query/string_parameters?with_some=additional_ones
```

The `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` value with `index.php?$1` on .htaccess is:

```
string(31) "this_is_query/string_parameters"
```

And with `index.php/$1`:

```
No input file specified.
```

On the Linux machine I have:

```
string(31) "with_some=additional_ones"
```

As response with `index.php/$1`.

Any thoughts?

---

I'm debugging the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` variable on the FIRST line of `index.php`, with NO interaction with Code Igniter whatsoever.

Yes, I do have `mod_rewrite`.

### THIS IS NOT THE SAME AS [Codeigniter no input file specified error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361742/codeigniter-no-input-file-specified-error)

I saw that question before asking this one. And I'm still with the issue.

I've added new information.

Comment: Try `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` when using index.php/$1.

Comment: With index.php/$1 I also get 'No input file specified' on PATH_INFO.

Comment: Yes, it is similar to that one, but not the same. I need to keep both my linux and windows machines with the same .htaccess. And on linux, the /$1 works perfectly. And also, I'm testing this without Code Igniter, so it's not a CI configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing [the QSA option](http://docforge.com/wiki/Mod_rewrite#Examples) to append the query string to the end:

```
RewriteRule \.svn/ - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

And to keep query params organized, I would suggest setting a parameter name, if allowed with CodeIgniter:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Not an option to use with Code Igniter. It needs the /$1

Answer (score 1):

Use  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L]`

Comment: I need to use index.php/$1, as this should be the same on both Linux and Windows. Can you please help me to reopen this question? Cheers :)