# Remove index.php from Codeigniter URL in subfolder with Wordpress in root

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm having some issues with a Codeigniter app in a subfolder on my server along with a Wordpress install in the document root.  If I hide the `index.php` of the Codeigniter URL with `.htaccess`

**/codeigniter/.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|user_guide|robots\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

And get Wordpress to ignore `/codeigniter` with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(codeigniter).*$`

**/.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(codeigniter).*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then navigate to `www.mysite.com/codeigniter/my_controller/my_function`, I get a 404 error `No input file specified.`  I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361742/codeigniter-no-input-file-specified-error), that adding a `?` after `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php` solves the Codeiginiter 404 error.

**/codeigniter/.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

However I'm now getting a Wordpress 404 error, so it seems if I replace `index.php` with `index.php?` in `/codeigniter/.htaccess`, the Wordpress rewrite rule in `/.htaccess`, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(codeigniter).*$` gets ignored.  Is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `RewriteBase` in the codeigniter directory should say `/codeigniter/`

```
RewriteBase /codeigniter
```

Otherwise the rewrite to `index.php` ends up going to wordpress' router.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured that out, FYI `RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]` also works.